# Where is the location of the downloads folder on a ChromeBook?

Tags: linux, chromebook

I just downloaded a chrome app called 'Terminal' so that I can connect to a remote server via SSH. This works perfectly, but when I need to use a .pem file to connect to an AWS instance, I need to include the path to the Downloads folder where the file is stored. I've been using the `ls` and `cd` commands to sort of snoop around the machine to see what's on it and I can't seem to find where it is. It's also a bit funny that inside of the `~/home/lnlance09/applications` folder nothing shows up despite the fact that I have several different apps installed.

Answer (score 16):

/home/chronos/user/Downloads/

file:///home/chronos/user/Downloads/ will show contents in browser

found at http://lcorg.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/google-chromebooks-some-helpful-tips.html

Comment: +1 for sure.  Let's me chomecast mp4 files this way.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

First you must enable "Linux Sharing" on your Downloads directory. Just right click on the Downloads directory, you should see the option. Then your downloads should be available at :

`/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Downloads`

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works for me when Linux was installed via the "Linux (Beta)" feature.

Answer (score 1):

unless you're in dev mode, they're nowhere.

we have to manually move them there, using Files.

[image: download files to linux terminal in chromebook]

Comment: Note that any files you move to the "Linux files" area in the files app will show up in the Linux terminal under /home/(your_username), and then you should be able to move them around as needed.

Comment: also note chromebooks are a terrible idea thanks to google being a terrible company. it's like living in your parents house, and they're passive aggressive jackasses who are always smiling and keeping the apparent "good neighbor" looks. and they even did fool me for way too long (apple is even worse, of course. and microsoft don't even try to pretend being good). **get a linux book or a linux-ish phone instead!** 

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple user accounts on the same chromebook, their download directories are in different locations. Each user account gets a long hex identifier, and their download directories are in `/home/chronos/u-[id]/Downloads`.